# Unable to set the APP_PORT on .env for Laravel Sail

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I have the following problem in Windows 10 (in Ubuntu works properly):

I'm working in Laravel 8 with Sail
When I create the `APP_PORT` variable on `.env`...

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_PORT=3000
```

...and launch the web with `sail up` I get this error:

```
services.laravel.test.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

This is how the `docker-compose.yml` looks

```
    version: '3'
    services:
        laravel.test:
            build:
                context: ./docker/8.0
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
                args:
                    WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
            image: sail-8.0/app
            ports:
                - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
...
```

I know that I could just put `ports: - '3000:80'` but since I'm working in team and the `php artisan sail:install` command will overwrite the `docker-compose.yml` file I don't wanna change the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `${APP_PORT:-80}:80` here `${APP_PORT:-80}` this is container port which will be 8000 as `php artisan serve` run on that port and `80` is you local machine port i think you want to change your local machine port ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Actually my Laravel Sail is serving on the port 80, I know by default artisan-serve one it's the 8000 but the 80 port it's the one tha 'sail up' is giving me. And I want to change my host port (on the left) I don't care the container port

Comment: use `- '${APP_PORT:-80}:${APP_CLIENT_PORT}'` and create a new in `.env`  be like `APP_CLIENT_PORT=3000`

Comment: @KamleshPaul what do you call "CLIENT" to? to the host or to the guest?

Comment: client means which will consume your port `docker(HOST)` your machine is client

Comment: Hi, I have the same configuration and didn't change docker.yml file, just added APP_PORT to .env and run sail up command, now I see the app running on localhost:8000 when I access through the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution for Laravel Sail (Docker) on Windows 10 was changing the `.env` EOL from CRLF to LF. I found it out because I was trying to resolve this warnings from another issue:

```
./.env: line X: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
```

After I resolved that EOL conflict the `sail up` command was able to read all the enviroment variables. I also changed the EOL to LR in the following files:

```
.env
artisan
docker/7.4/start-container
docker/8.0/start-container
vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0/start-container
vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4/start-container
```

It's clear why this problem wasnt present on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks very much! I had the same issue with sail reading the .env file and changing to LF resolved it for me.

Answer (score 18):

run sail in

```
sudo APP_PORT=3001 ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

thats the only way i made is work. is still dont know why other configurations dont allow it in .env

Comment: Well, this did not solve my problem, I had to go to docker-composer.yml file in my laravel project and edited these two lines for the port from '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'  to  '${APP_PORT:-89}:80' and ${HMR_PORT:-808-}:8080'     ----> ${HMR_PORT:-8084}:8080'     and everything worked like charming.

Answer (score 17):

There’s no need to change docker-compose.yml file, just adding a line on your .env file should work:

1. on your .env file add a line

   `APP_PORT=3001 //or instead of 3001 any other port number of your choice`
2. restart Sail

   `sail up`
3. Now you should be able to access your application with the port number you set on step 1

   `http://localhost:3001`

Comment: Well, this did not solve my problem, I had to go to docker-composer.yml file in my laravel project and edited these two lines for the port from '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'  to  '${APP_PORT:-89}:80' and ${HMR_PORT:-808-}:8080'     ----> ${HMR_PORT:-8084}:8080'     and everything worked like charming.

Comment: @NamwanzaRonald I am not sure but in your case as you are editing HMR_PORT value as well so may be if you also add "HMR_PORT=8084" on your .env file it might solve the problem of having not to edit your docker file, please let me know if this works, thanks.\

Comment: well, that  did not work for me either, like I said, editing my docker-composer file saved my sleepless night.

Comment: Yes it is working, although it's a little bit confusing after running the "sail up" command, I can see in the command line:
"INFO  Server running on [http://0.0.0.0:80].",
which conveys the idea that the new port mapping hasn't do anything and it's still (trying) to use port 80..

Answer (score 4):

add to your .env:

```
SERVER_PORT=3001
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: When containerizing an existing Laravel 7 app in Docker, this was the needed fix. `APP_PORT` was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Foollowing are the ports that you will must set / change in the `.env` file if any of them are already taken:

```
APP_PORT=8011
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
FORWARD_REDIS_PORT=6380
FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT=7701
FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT=1026
FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT=8026
VITE_PORT=5174
```